# Different way retrieve images from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have written the php code for storing images in a mysql database and I also know how to retrieve them, but is there a way i can retrieve them via URL, just the way we access facebook images. I mean providing the URL of the mysql database and then somehow getting those images. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the images in files, and just use the database as an index. Then you can have URLs that point directly to the files.

Answer (score 2):

Upload your images

```
$imageName = "123.jpg";
$saveImg = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $imageName;
```

Then run a database query to set the user image URL ("upload/123.jpg")

```
INSERT INTO images (imageUrl) VALUES ('upload/123.jpg');
```

To show the image, run a SELECT query then have something similar to:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['imageUrl']; ?>" alt="my image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - you can store images as a blobs in database.
Unfortunately, MySQL has some limitations. For example, default buffer size for blob is only 1 MB. It can be increased, but server config may need to be tweaked.

And PHP can read that blob from db, format it using appropriate MIME type and send it to browser.

Comment: Thanks, thats makes sense, but is your solution similar to this other answer.